# Is a lapsed Advanced Ground Instructor certificate acceptable to use as proof of FOI when taking CFI initial?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa-knowledge-test

I have an AGI certificate that I haven't exercised the privileges of in the preceding 24 calendar months.

When I initially got the AGI, I had planned to take my CFI almost immediately but didn't. I'm having trouble locating the regulation that shows that since I have my AGI, I don't have to re-take the FOI written to complete my CFI.

What regulation states that this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## That would be 61.183(e)(1):

> To be eligible for a flight instructor certificate or rating a person
> must:
>
> (e) Pass a knowledge test on the areas listed in Sec. 61.185(a)(1) of
> this part, unless the applicant:
>
> (1) Holds a flight instructor certificate or ground instructor certificate issued under this part;

Comment: I'm guessing since it doesn't say anything about it being lapsed that it's not a factor in meeting that regulation?

Comment: @Canuk - Right. Imagine if your AGI was an airplane and the requirement was "must own an airplane". Just because your airplane is out of annual right now doesn't mean you don't still own it.

Comment: Nice analogy. Thanks!